# PHP error whilst confirming successful row insertion

Tags: php, mysql

people

Overview i am crating a dummy website for learning purposes therefore its functionalists are basic and security in not on the agenda atm.

I am experiencing this minor problem that i cant resolve. So why i am trying to do is to add a new account and echo a message saying that the insertion was suspenseful, but i get an error message in a place where i want to add a new record saying that the variable which suppose to hold the message is undefined.

A lil more: So when i am in the Home page of the wbesite and click a register button that is when the error message pops up but when i actually submit a query to add a account that error message changes to the message i want to show.

```
<?php



if(isset($_POST['submited'])){

    include('connect_mysql.php');


    $username= $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $firstname = $_POST['first_name'];
    $lastname = $_POST['last_name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];

    $NewAccountQuery = "INSERT INTO users (username, password, first_name, last_name, email) VALUES ('$username','$password', '$firstname', '$lastname', '$email')";

    if(!mysql_query($NewAccountQuery)){

        die(mysql_error());

    }//end of nested if statment

    if($NewAccountQuery){
         echo $confirm = "1 record added to the database";
    }
}//end of if statment

?>
<html>
<head>

<title>Home Page</title>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>

    <div id="wrapper">
        <header><h1>E-Shop</h1></header>


        <article>
        <h1>Welcome</h1>

            <h1>Create Account</h1>

        <div id="login">

                <ul id="login">

                <form method="post" action="register.php"  >
                    <fieldset>  
                        <legend>Fill in the form</legend>

                        <label>Select Username : <input type="text" name="username" /></label>
                        <label>Password : <input type="password" name="password" /></label>
                        <label>Enter First Name : <input type="text" name="first_name" /></label>
                        <label>Enter Last Name : <input type="text" name="last_name" /></label>
                        <label>Enter E-mail Address: <input type="text" name="email" /></label>
                    </fieldset>
                        <br />

                        <input name="submited" type="submit" submit="submit" value="Create Account" class="button">

                </form>




                </div>
            <form action="index.php" method="post">
            <div id="login">
                <ul id="login">
                    <li>
                        <input type="submit" value="back" onclick="index.php" class="button">   
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>      
            </form>


        </article>
<aside>

                <?php print $confirm; ?>


</aside>

<div id="footer">This is my site i Made coppyrights 2013 Tomazi</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

ok here is the image before i submit the query:
[image]

Image after i submit the query:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo $confirm = "1 record added to the database";
```

Should be:

```
$confirm = "1 record added to the database";
echo $confirm;
```

It looks like you don't need the echo there as you echo it else where. If all you want to do is assign `$confirm` to `1 record added to the database`, then you just need to assign it, without the echo. Echo basically outputs it to the html in the same way print does.

Comment: ok this works but displays the message at the top of the page somewhere but i want this message to be visible in <aside> section of my html.

                'code' <aside><?php print $confirm; ?>


</aside> 'code'

Comment: Right, so at the top where you process your form, just assign your text to `$confirm`. Then where you want it to show up do: `print $confirm;`

Comment: ok i have tried this and it has exactly the same affect an Error;

Comment: Look at @ExplosionPills post below. It will throw an error the first time it loads as you haven't defined it.

Comment: ok it works now I am sorry as I stated am a lame beginner :) at PHP but thx to people like you and @ExplosionPills i can learn and move forward......

Comment: And I will probably get more issues and will refer to this site so guys please dont get put off :D regards

Comment: Just remember, anytime you want to print/echo/use a variable in a programming language, it must first be defined.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the error message is pretty clear.  `$confirm` is not defined.  You only define it in the "successful query" section.  A simple solution is to define it before the entire `if(isset($_POST['submited'])){` block.  Just put `$confirm = '';` and nothing will be printed out.

---

Some notes:

Since you are learning and this is all new, you should **stop** using ext/mysql now and [use `PDO` or `mysqli`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) as your DB engine (I prefer the former).

Also, `if($NewAccountQuery){` is not very meaningful.  It will always be true since it's just a string you define earlier.  If you switch to `PDO` you could check [`PDOStatement::rowCount`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php).

Answer (score 1):

Basically the problem is when you load the homepage for the first time - it won't go into the `if(isset($_POST['submited']))` condition since $_POST['submitted'] is not set. And since you are setting the $confirm inside this loop, This statement                 `<?php print $confirm; ?>` won't find $confirm variable set. Hence it will give out PHP NOTICE.. So like someone said here either set `$confirm = '';` before if condition or you can do something like this while printing

```
<?php 
if(isset($confirm))
   print $confirm; 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are just echoing or printing the string you don't need to assign it to a variable first. Either of these would work:

```
echo '1 record added to the database';
```

OR

```
$confirm = '1 record added to the database';
echo $confirm;
```

Comment: ok this works but displays the message at the top of the page somewhere but i want this message to be visible in <aside> section of my html.

                'code' <aside><?php print $confirm; ?>


</aside>'code'

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submited'])){

    include('connect_mysql.php');

    $username= $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $firstname = $_POST['first_name'];
    $lastname = $_POST['last_name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];

    $NewAccountQuery = "INSERT INTO users VALUES ('$username','$password', '$firstname', '$lastname', '$email')"; // simplified query if those are only 5 cols in order
    $result = mysql_query($NewAccountQuery);

    if($result){
       $confirm = "1 record added to the database";
    } else {
        exit('error inserting row');
    }
}
?>
```